# Does ptr = &a and *ptr = a mean the same?

Tags: c, pointers

In the book it explains:

```
ptr = &a /* set ptr to point to a */

*ptr = a /* '*' on left:set what ptr points to */
```

They seem the same to me, aren't they?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  The first one changes the pointer (it now points at `a`).  The second one changes the thing that the pointer is pointing at.

Consider:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;

int *ptr = &b;

if (first_version) {
    ptr = &a;
    // The value of a and b haven't changed.
    // ptr now points at a instead of b
}
else {
    *ptr = a;
    // The value of b is now 5
    // ptr still points at b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, in  `ptr = &a` you are storing the address of variable 'a' in variable 'ptr'
i.e., something like `ptr=0xef1f23`.

in `*ptr = a` you are storing the value of variable 'a' in pointer variable '*ptr'
i.e., something like `*ptr=5`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no. But to explain the similar behaviour, Adding to Oli Charlesworth's answer:

Consider:

```
int a = 5;
int* ptr = new int;

if(first_version) {
  ptr = &a;
  //ptr points to 5 (using a accesses the same memory location)
} else {
  *ptr = a;
  //ptr points to 5 at a different memory location
  //if you change a now, *ptr does not change 
}
```

edit: sorry for using `new` (c++ not c) but the pointer thing does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Both are not same.

**If u modify the value of a = 10. Then print again *ptr. It will print only 5. not 10.**

```
*ptr = a; //Just copies the value of a to the location where ptr is pointing.
ptr = &a; //Making the ptr to point the a
```

Comment: Trying learning [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) as is used to parse stackoverflow questions/answers. It helps a lot. You could also click edit on other people's answers to see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

`*ptr=&a` C++ compiler will genrate error becoz u r going to assign addres to adres
`ptr=&a`,this is true here ptr working like variable and &a is a addres of a which contain some value

check and try

```
int *ptr,a=10;
ptr=&a;output=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

*ptr=&a signifies that our pointer is pointing towards address of the variable a
while
*ptr=a signifies that our pointer is pointing towards value a

Answer (score -1):

*ptr = &a is not technically correct.
int *ptr = &a; is correct ..... Way (i)
(or)
int *ptr;
ptr = &a; is correct ..........Way (ii)
Here *ptr is a pointer to integer datatype.

int *ptr;
*ptr = a; This means ptr becomes a NULL pointer [i.e. it does not point to any memory location]. *ptr holds the value of a.

Comment: _"`int *ptr;`... means `ptr` becomes a null pointer"_ is wrong. After the declaration `int *ptr;`, `ptr` takes an indeterminate value. You can instead provide the definition `int *ptr = NULL;` after which `ptr` does become a null pointer. Further, `*ptr = a;` causes undefined behavior in either case because it attempts to use the unary `*` operator on an invalid pointer (here either a null pointer or an uninitialized pointer are considered invalid).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).